# Uploading a file from Android to DJango. Request.FILES is always empty

Tags: php, android, python, django

I'm trying to upload a file to Django using the following code on my Android application:

```
            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(screenshotFile), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverAddress);
            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I've found many posts that stateing that the previous code works on other servers like PHP, but for some reason, the `request.FILES` dictionary is empty, hence, I can't do anything with the uploaded file. The next method helps me check the values inside `request.FILES` and `request.POST` (also empty)

The following

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    print request.FILES
    print request.POST
    return HttpResponse("")
```

I've also tried replacing the use of `InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(screenshotFile), -1)` with `FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(screenshotFile, "application/octet-stream")` -as stated in other answers- but the same thing happens.

Probably I should be looking elsewhere and not in `request.FILES`. Does anyone have any clue of how to solve this?

**EDIT**

I have already tested `MultipartEntityBuilder` and it works but that means to add extra jars* to the project and  I'd rather not.

Comment: Try `MultipartEntity` instead

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Thanks for commenting. I editted the question to reply to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/):

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method
>   was `POST` and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute
>   `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.

When you send data as you're doing, Django will probably find the content in `request.BODY` instead of `request.FILES`.

So you have to use a `MultipartEntityBuilder` or set manually your request (e.g. by manipulating headers) so that Django recognizes it as a `multipart/form-data`, but I can't tell you this will work.

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem if it were on `request.body` but the problem is that `len(request.body)`  is `0`, so I'm guessing it isn't there as well. Do you know how can I manually manipulate the request?

Comment: At the end, I had to go with `MultipartEntityBuilder` because setting manually the request was too much trouble.